# WEB API function has stopped working - won't recognize JSON structure

Tags: vb.net, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

A function in my API, that has worked without problems for years, stopped working a week ago. The API has numerous functions but only this one has stopped.

I updated a couple of NUGET packages before the problem occurred. I have since reverted them to the versions prior to the problem. There have been no other changes to the code. The site uses Knockout, which has caused me problems in the past, so maybe the JSON has changed. The JSON object looks good to me. I will paste it below. The project uses Newtonsoft JSON.NET

The API function is supposed to accept the JSON structure as a LINQ class, which it has always done. However, the class appears as Nothing when the API call is fired:

[image: data As EditEqGroup]

If I change the data type to Object, the JSON is received:

[image: data As Object]

I have tried to work around the problem but I have not been able to get JSON.NET to convert it to the LINQ class. The text is below. I would really appreciate any clues.

Raw JSON text:

```
{"EdEquipmentGroupID":"64ad9365-1e61-4133-bd8c-38ff70b0fdd6","EdEquipmentGroupName":"Incubators","EdEquipmentGroupCurrent":true,"EdEquipmentGroupRules":[{"RuleName":"Logging Interval (Minutes)","RuleUse":1,"RuleValue":"10"},{"RuleName":"Rollover (Yes or No)","RuleUse":1,"RuleValue":"Yes"},{"RuleName":"Download Interval Required (Days)","RuleUse":1,"RuleValue":"6"},{"RuleName":"Temperature Low Limit (°C)","RuleUse":1,"RuleValue":"36.7"},{"RuleName":"Temperature High Limit (°C)","RuleUse":1,"RuleValue":"37.2"},{"RuleName":"Temperature Low Permitted Consecutive (Minutes)","RuleUse":1,"RuleValue":"30"},{"RuleName":"Temperature High Permitted Consecutive (Minutes)","RuleUse":1,"RuleValue":"30"},{"RuleName":"Disable Alerts (Yes or No)","RuleUse":1,"RuleValue":"No"}]}
```

After formatting for readability:

```
{
    "EdEquipmentGroupID": "64ad9365-1e61-4133-bd8c-38ff70b0fdd6",
    "EdEquipmentGroupName": "Incubators",
    "EdEquipmentGroupCurrent": true,
    "EdEquipmentGroupRules": [
        {
            "RuleName": "Logging Interval (Minutes)",
            "RuleUse": 1,
            "RuleValue": "10"
        },
        {
            "RuleName": "Rollover (Yes or No)",
            "RuleUse": 1,
            "RuleValue": "Yes"
        },
        {
            "RuleName": "Download Interval Required (Days)",
            "RuleUse": 1,
            "RuleValue": "6"
        },
        {
            "RuleName": "Temperature Low Limit (°C)",
            "RuleUse": 1,
            "RuleValue": "36.7"
        },
        {
            "RuleName": "Temperature High Limit (°C)",
            "RuleUse": 1,
            "RuleValue": "37.2"
        },
        {
            "RuleName": "Temperature Low Permitted Consecutive (Minutes)",
            "RuleUse": 1,
            "RuleValue": "30"
        },
        {
            "RuleName": "Temperature High Permitted Consecutive (Minutes)",
            "RuleUse": 1,
            "RuleValue": "30"
        },
        {
            "RuleName": "Disable Alerts (Yes or No)",
            "RuleUse": 1,
            "RuleValue": "No"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So, to clarify, your code worked fine with the old NuGet packages, but after updating them this one function stopped working.  And after you put them back to the old packages it works again?  So, what NuGet package(s) did you update?  Also, what do you mean by "LINQ class"?  Do mean just a regular class, or is there something special about it?  Perhaps you can post the `EditEqGroup` class definition in your question?

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for the reply. Sorry my terminology is unclear. I reached the conclusion that somehow the JSON is malformed by something in the site, which was built by someone else five years ago and relies heavily on Knockout.

The EditEqGroup is a regular class. I ended up writing extra code to parse the "JSON" text and populate the class to get things working again. The problem is sorted out for now. Thanks again.